# How to maven build child projects?

Tags: maven, aggregation

I have aggregation where I link a parent Pom using the `<modules>` element, and then I have the `<parent>` specified in each child pom.

Is there a way I can build only a subset of the child modules from the parent pom... i.e.

```
cd parent-dir
mvn install subproj1 subproj2
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can run Maven like this: `mvn install -pl subproj1,subproj2`

PS: another good Maven command to try: `mvn -?`

Comment: For those who might see this post and end up trying to use it, note that it the -pl command is PL not P1.